# How do you throw char* exceptions properly in a member function?

Tags: c++, exception

im having some trouble with exception handling. So, I have a test program that is supposed to catch a char* exception, and I cant figure out to throw the exception in the member function. I figured it would be something like: 
throw "pos cant be a negative number";
but no matter what i try, i get the error message saying "terminating with uncaught exception of type char const*".

Thanks a lot guys, im a newbie!

Comment: A [mcve] please, so that we can see what you actually have tried.

Comment: Do you see the `const` keyword, in there?

Comment: Try catching a `char const*` instead of a `char*`,

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to throw a `char*` directly. Yes, the C++ standard technically allows it, but in practice it is rarely useful. You should instead throw a [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) derived class, such as [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) :

```
throw std::out_of_range("pos cant be a negative number");
```

And then you can catch it by type:

```
catch (const std::out_of_range &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Or:

```
catch (const std::logic_error &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Or:

```
catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It could be argued that throwing a builtin type is better because it cannot fail due to out-of-memory; whereas throwing a class-type exception may fail to allocate the exception object.  But most people seem to just ignore this possibility

Comment: @m.m because crossing the edge of memory capacity are usually impossible to recover from.  On some systems, small allocations failing in a process happens after the entire system starts crashing process by process.  There are situations where worrying about out of memory errors matters, but treating out of memory as unrecoverable and hardening your application against damage from a sudden halt is probably more useful for many problem domains.